# Polymorphism feature fails in case of sort() function for python and How do we sort Imaginary numbers in python?

Tags: python, sorting, complex-numbers

Ideally sort() function is superb example of **Polymorphism**. In case of sort() function, you can sort almost anything with it.

```
In [27]: b
Out[27]: [3, 4, 5, 6]

In [28]: b = ['a','b',5,6,None]

In [29]: b.sort()

In [30]: b
Out[30]: [None, 5, 6, 'a', 'b']

In [31]: b = ['a','b',23,'c',None,5j]

In [32]: b.sort()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/dubizzle/webapps/django/dubizzle/<ipython-input-32-fc40da74ac51> in <module>()
----> 1 b.sort()

TypeError: no ordering relation is defined for complex numbers
```

but it seems that in case of imaginary numbers sort() function fails. Please note that I am getting this error **TypeError: no ordering relation is defined for complex numbers**.

So My questions are

1. Where exactly this ordering is defined ? How sort() function works internally ?
2. Is there any purpose for leaving this ordering relation for complex numbers or it just left out similarly as we have no power operator in c language **( A mistake)**.
3. How do **we sort the imaginary (complex) numbers** in python basically ? Do we have a pythonic way to do this ?

Comment: The problem here isn't about python. It's about data type. There is no defined way to sort complex numbers. You'll have to pass your sort function to `sorted` using the `key` parameter

Comment: FYI most of these lists can't be sorted in Python 3 -- e.g. `sorted([3, '3'])` raises `TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()` -- due to the cleanup of comparisons.  Most of us consider this a significant improvement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In mathematical terms, the set of complex numbers cannot be a totally ordered set; defining an order for them requires you to provide a key by which they can be ordered. This depends on what you want: do you want to order them by their real values?

```
b.sort(key=lambda complex_: complex_.real)
```

By their imaginary values?

```
b.sort(key=lambda complex_: complex_.imag)
```

By their magnitude?

```
b.sort(key=lambda complex_: sqrt(complex_.real**2 + complex_.imag**2))
```

However you want to order them, you specify a function to compare elements using the key keyword.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort by real part, or imaginary part this way:

```
>>> x = [(1+2j),(2+3j),(2+1j),(7+4j),(2+2j)]
>>> sorted(x, key=lambda x: x.real)
[(1+2j), (2+1j), (2+2j), (2+3j), (7+4j)]
>>> sorted(x, key=lambda x: x.imag)
[(2+1j), (1+2j), (2+2j), (2+3j), (7+4j)]
```

or:

```
>>> sorted(x, key=lambda x: (x.real, x.imag))
[(1+2j), (2+1j), (2+2j), (2+3j), (7+4j)]
```

Complex numbers do not have a natural ordering, so you have to specify in what manner you want to sort them.